# Dynamic index String slicing in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column with either a single integer value or a range of two integers. I want to create a final column where the range values are averaged, so that the column become purely integer.

I am trying to use pandas.str.find("-") to find the location of break point and then use np.where() to create separate columns for First Value and Second Value in Range.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'A' : ['1234', '12 - 16'], 'Avg':[1234, 14]}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)

df['bp'] = df['A'].str.find("-")
df['F'] = np.where(df['bp']>0, df['A'].str.slice(0, df['bp']), df['A'])
```

I am getting NAN where range is present in column. Expected Output is in Column "Avg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.split`

```
df['A'].str.split(' - ').apply(lambda s: sum(map(int,s))/len(s),1)
```

---

```
0    1234.0
1      14.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using vectorization (with out apply function like below) using str function and explode **(pandas above 0.25)**

your index must be unique or you need to call `df.reset_index` for this to work

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'A' : ['1234', '12 - 16'], 'Avg':[1234, 14]}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
df["A"].str.split("-").explode().astype(pd.np.int).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is vectorized? Using `split` and `explode` doesn't sound vectorized at all to me ;] . In fact, this solution is actually slower than using plain apply (which in turn Is likely bit slower than a simple list comprehension itself here)

Answer (score 0):

Use `extractall` and call `mean` directly on `level=0`

```
df.A.str.extractall(r'(\d+)').astype(int).mean(level=0)[0]

Out[64]:
0    1234
1      14
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```